# Change Icon Bars Bootstrap Toggle Menu On Hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do you change the colors of the icon bars when hovering the toggle navigation simultaneously? Currently the toggle bars only change when hovering over each individual icon bar. Also how would you change the thickness of the icon bars?

CSS:

```
    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{
    background: #dbdbdb;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar:hover {
    background: white;
}
```

HTML: 
         
      
        
           
            Toggle navigation
            
            
            
          
           
            
              ×
              Home
              Link
              Link
              Link
              Link

Comment: Could you add your markup?  Otherwise we're going into this without all the info needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change icon-bar color when your cursor is over .navbar-toggle use this code:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover .icon-bar {
    background: color_for_icon-bar_backgorund;
}
```

And to make icon-bar elements thicker change height here:

```
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    height: 4px;
}
```